# jquery token input plugin not passing the id from the select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, jquery-tokeninput

I am working on a simple rails plugin where a user can select a form containing the list of school available in the database. My problem is that the list of schools is being fetched but if I select the rest of the schools in the array I get the first item's id. What could I be doing wrong? My code sample is as follows

my user model has

```
belongs_to :school

  attr_reader :school_tokens

  def school_tokens=(id)
    self.school_id = id.split(",")
  end
```

then in my school model I have

```
has_many :users
```

in my form I have

```
<%= f.label :school, "School Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :school_tokens %>
```

my application.js looks like

```
$(function(){
  $('#user_school_tokens').tokenInput("/school_streets.json", {
      crossDomain: false,
      tokenLimit: 1
  });
```

finally my schools controller is like this

```
  def index
    @school_streets = SchoolStreet.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @school_streets.map(&:attributes) }
    end
  end
```

Note: the schools display very well, but when I select a school, for instance the second school in the list, and submit the form it saves with only the first school's id in the list.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `tokenLimit: 1` means you can only select one 'school' at a time. Remove this to submit multiple.